# I can't upload PDF file in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, formidable

I'm trying to create a simple form which can upload file(pdf & image) and texts together using Node.js. Nonetheless, I don't wanna save the pdf file to MySql database, rather I want it to be kept in my internal storage "./uploads" folder. I have used npm *formidable, mv, and multer*, yet nothing works, anybody knows why?

Here's my html form

```
                <form action="/auth/registerEvent" method = "POST">
                <h5> Enter Your Event Information</h5>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="eventName">Event Name</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eventName" name="eventName" placeholder="Event Name">
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="eventDescription">Description</label>
                      <textarea class="form-control" id="eventDescription" name="eventDescription" placeholder="Event Description: No more than 200 words" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="eventPoster">Poster</label>
                        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="eventPoster" name="eventPoster" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept=".jpg, .png, .jpeg">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="eventProposal">Sponsor Proposal</label>
                        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="eventProposal" name="eventProposal" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept=".pdf">
                    </div>
                    <br>
                
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                  </form>
```

This is my app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config({path: './.env'}); // connect to .env

// set views folder
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', require('hbs').__express);


// set the directory to css and js
const publicDirectory = path.join(__dirname, './public');
app.use(express.static(publicDirectory));

// Parse URL encoded bodies (as sent by HTML Form)
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
// Parse JSON bodies (as sent by API clients)
app.use(express.json());

// Define routes
app.use('/', require('./router/pages.js'));
app.use('/auth', require('./router/auth.js'));

// connect to mysql
const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.LOCALHOST,
    user: process.env.USER,
    password: process.env.PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DATABASE,
});

db.connect( (err) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log('Database is connected');
} )



// laptop server
app.listen(3000, (req, res)=>{
    console.log('Server is running at localhost:3000');
});
```

and finally the "auth.js"

```
const formidable = require('formidable');
const fs = require('fs');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.LOCALHOST,
    user: process.env.USER,
    password: process.env.PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DATABASE,
});




exports.registerEvent = (req, res) => {
    const {
        eventName, eventInstitution, 
        // eventStartDate, eventEndDate,
        eventAddress, eventDescription,
        eventPoster, eventProposal,
        // eoName, eoPhone, eoEmail
    } = req.body;

    if (req.url === "/registerEvent") {
        const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
            const oldPath = eventPoster.path;
            const newPath = './uploads' + eventPoster;
            fs.rename(oldPath, newPath, function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;

            });
        })
    }

    // db start
    db.query('INSERT INTO registerevent SET ? ', {
        EventName: eventName,
        Institution: eventInstitution,
        // StartDate: eventStartDate,
        // EndDate: eventEndDate,
        Address: eventAddress,
        Description: eventDescription,
        // Poster: eventPoster,
        // Proposal: eventProposal,
        // ContactName: eoName,
        // PhoneNumber: eoPhone,
        // Email: eoEmail,
    }, (error, result) => {
        if (error) { console.log(error); }
        else {
            res.statusCode = 302;
            res.setHeader("Location", "/feedback");
            res.end();
        }
    });
    // db end


}
```

So when the customer enters the name & address it goes to sql, and the poster and proposal files will be sent to my "/uploads" directory. Please help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example